php getting null date if value is not set by user
I have a html form with a date input.If i disable the input and set its value to a specific date when inserting this value to MySQL I get 1970-01-01 (null date). If I let the user choose the date from then input it works fine and the choose date is stored.
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

   $datai = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['datai']));

<input type="date" class="form-control" name="datai" placeholder="" id="datai">

document.getElementById("datai").disabled = true;


tried to remove the date and strtotime but got index error.

You should check to see if the input is empty, and if not, set a default value.

strtotime() returns false if the argument isn't a valid date, and an empty string is invalid. false is coerced to 0 when used as a number by date(), and that's the epoch date.

your question is not clear kind of do you want to add a default value in case if the user will not choose a date or you want to add today's date and disable the input from the user

I set its default value like this:  document.getElementById("datai").value = data2;

If it's disabled and you want to set a default, why even have the input in the form at all? You can just set the default value in PHP when saving it, or even set the value as the default for the column in the database and not setting in in your code at all.

I set its default value like this:
document.getElementById("datai").value = data2;
data2 comes from a php sql query using a XMLHttpRequest.
the date (data2) is displayed in the control (datai).

@Abdurrahman Alsallakh
if a condition is met I let the user choose the date (interact with the control - in this case the date is correctly inserted in the table), otherwise i get the date from another table in the database, display it in the control and disable it (in this case the date is not inserted, instead is null).

Disabled inputs aren't sent to the server. If you want to prevent the user from modifying it, make it readonly, not disabled.
